# Powerpivot - one stored procedure 2 filtered reports?

Tags: powerpivot

I am new to PowerPivot. I created a flat pivot using data returned by a stored procedure (sql server). Then someone requested filtering the data to create 2 reports (2 worksheets).  They are the same except one includes codes 50 and 95 and the other is everything else.

I modified my stored proc with a param and created 2 "tables" in PP.  I wasn't sure if this was something I could do in PP without modifying the proc. If I filter in the spreadsheet, I can only pick things to include, not exclude. If an item is later added I don't think it would get picked up.  Is there a way to do this all on the PP end?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a filter or slicer selection in a pivot report. The filter list is preserved across model refresh. There's no need to have duplicate tables to maintain separate filters.